# css absolute positioning different on FF/chrome between windows and mac

Tags: css

I am using the following test. In firefox/chrome/safari on my mac, panel1 renders above panel2. But on firefox/chrome on my windows machine, it renders underneath.

I want panel1 to be placed directly over panel2. What's the right way to do it?:

```
<html>

    <head>
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Appears on top of panel2 in safari/chrome/ff on mac, but underneath on windows. -->
        <div id='panel1' style='z-index:6; position:absolute; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red'>
        </div>

        <div id='panel2' style='z-index:3; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:yellow'>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

I was shown this trick in a previous question. I can't set the top/left position of panel1 (I think) because it's in a larger nest of divs that will move around the screen as the user resizes their browser frame.

Thanks

----------- Update -------------

Tried to explicitly set z-index on both divs, that worked.

Comment: FYI, here is a page which gives some examples of the default z-index. Try setting it explicitly as has been suggested.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index/Stacking_without_z-index

Comment: IIRC `z-index` doesn't change a thing if the elements have different 'flows' (forgot what it's called in the spec).  Because one div has a static position and the other has an absolute position, their z-indices don't relate.

Comment: Also, using the exact markup in the post, this seems to show red in all browsers: http://jsbin.com/ehuho3

Comment: @strager, are you trying on a windows version of chrome tho - on mac, I get red for all browsers, but on my window machine (latest version of all browsers) I see yellow.

Comment: @user246114, Yes, I did try on a Windows machine.  I'm 100% sure this is doing as you want.  Maybe you're loading the wrong file?

Comment: Ugh you're right, I'm sorry. I'm using youtube's player api, it replaces the div in question with an <object> element, and on windows this seems to require a special parameter for the z-indexing to work. Sorry about that, thanks for your help.

Comment: Aww, and I had BrowserShots set up : http://browsershots.org/http://jsbin.com/ehuho3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div id='panel2' style='z-index:3; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:yellow'>
    </div>

    <div id='panel1' style='z-index:5; position:absolute; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red'>
    </div>
```

Like this maybe? Swap the position of the 2.

Comment: Same - panel2 still appearing above panel1!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `z-index` style on `panel1`?